# Translating sentences into first-order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm having some trouble translating these sentences into first-order logic - any idea where to begin? Thanks!

"Consider a first-order language, with relation symbols < and =, and the constant symbol 0. Consider the interpretation: the natural numbers, with 'less than' and 'equality', and the distinguished element 0. Formalise the following statements:

- There is a smallest number
- There is no largest number
- Every number has an immediate successor
- Every number is greater than some other number
- There is some number that every other number is greater than"

Comment: What have you tried? No idea?

Comment: Start from the first one: it is very simple.

Comment: I've done some others, but not these ones. Would the first one just be "¬∃x(x<0)"?

Comment: For example for the first one. It can be converted to "I have a number and whatever number you give me, my number will be smaller than yours." "I have" can then be translated to "There exists a number" and "whatever" is another way to say "for all".

Comment: @Mauro Or would that be closer to "0 is the smallest number"?

Comment: Correct; given the language you have described, $0$ is the smallest number, meaning that there is no number smaller than zero: $\lnot \exists x (x < 0)$ or equivalently, every number is "not-smaller" than zero: $\forall x \lnot (x < 0)$.

Comment: Now you can go on with the second one.

Comment: Would it be ¬∃x∀y(y≤x)?

Comment: Also, for "every number has an immediate successor", how would one show that the successor is *immediate*?

Comment: @why_did_i_do_this_course: Every number has a number which is greater than $x$ and if there is a $y$ which is also a successor, then this number is either equal to $x$ or greater than $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Here some comments and hints:

- $\neg\exists x(x<0)$ means: "*There is no number smaller than 0*". If you want the exact translation of "*There is a smallest number*", it should be: $\exists x\forall y (x\leq y)$. That is: "*There is a $x$ such that, for every $y$, $x$ is smaller or equal to $y$*".
- Your second answer is correct: $\neg\exists x\forall y (y\leq x)$.
- For the third, I will only give you a hint: since you don't have a successor function, consider this: For every x, there is a y greater than x, such that there is nothing else between them. Figure out yourself how to express that.
- Fourth: this is very easy, you don't need a hint. Note that this is false: 0 is not greater than any other number, since all our objects are natural numbers. But a false statement is still a statement.
- Fifth: this is similar to the first.